# Como creo contratos de servicios en webapi

Tags: rest, soap, asp.net-core, wcf

Estoy haciendo un API en .Net Core 2.0 y necesito saber como se crea un contrato de servicio partiendo del patron SOA Contract Centralization

http://soapatterns.org/design_patterns/contract_centralization

> En WCF, se crea el WSDL y las clases se marcan con [ServiceContract] y
>   [DataContract]. Es similar en un API REST?

Answer (score 2):

Dale una mirada a especificación [OpenAPI](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification) que es la forma de definir "estos contratos" (como lo es WSDL)

Por ejemplo una de las herramienta que utilizamos en WebAPI para definir nuestras API y hacerlas mas "legibles para nosotros los humanos es " [Swagger](https://swagger.io/) (la mas popular), solo con decoradores genera el esquema necesario para que se pueda leer en estos herramientas. O sea genera el contrato.

Tambien podes ver [Autorest](https://github.com/Azure/autorest) que es la herramienta que con una especificion OpenAPI genera el cliente para acceder a dicha API! O sea para escribir menos codigo ;)

Enlaces que te pueden ayudar

- OpenAPI | 
  https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification
- Swagger https://swagger.io/